# KendoUI Autocomplete with custom datasource read function

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-autocomplete

I'm using the Kendo UI autocomplete widget within a framework (not Kendo's MVVM framework). As such, I've defined a read function in the datasource configuration that returns my data, instead of using a string url reference. A snippet of my configuration is below:

```
        transport: {
            read: function (opts) {
                console.log('arguments', arguments);
                readFn(opts)
                    .then(opts.success)
                    .catch(e => opts.error([]));
            }
        }
```

My problem is that when I type into the autocomplete, the current text value of the autocomplete doesn't get passed to my custom read function. This means that I can't dynamically filter using the function. (I expected this to be passed as part of the `opts` hash passed to the function.)

Kendo provides a `serverFiltering` option, but this doesn't appear to do anything when using a custom function. So essentially, what this means - upon typing initially, Kendo will attempt to run the function, but then it will filter the data internally after that. That's not the behavior I'm looking for.

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was, of course, something that I was doing. I was indeed setting the `serverFiltering` option, but I was passing it as part of the main options hash, not part of the Datasource. Changing this to be the correct way fixed the issue.

Comment: You just saved me from hours of beating my head against the wall - seriously, thank you.